# Letsencrypt certificate output for golang ListenAndServeTLS

Tags: ssl, go, lets-encrypt

Lets'Encrypt provided me with a "Signed Certificate" and an "Intermediate Certificate". I had to create a private key domain.key for the domain before.

Now [ListenAndServeTLS](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServeTLS) expects a certificate and a key file.

I guess the "keyfile" is the locally generated domain.key file but what do I do with a "Signed Certificate" and an "Intermediate Certificate" if ListenAndServeTLS expects two files?

Comment: why don't you use nginx or similar in front of go web server?

Comment: @pregmatch: there's no reason to add another proxy layer if it's not needed.

Comment: i am asking that because of ssl and keys and stuff. so you do not have to worry about that things. i did like many 10 aps in go web server and all of them are using nginx in front. it is much easier for me to do continuous integration and stuff like that and i do not have to worry about ssl and stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most http servers, the Go tls server implementation only accepts a single file for the certificate. From the `net/http` documentation:

> If the certificate is signed by a certificate authority, the certFile should be the concatenation of the server's certificate, any intermediates, and the CA's certificate.

All you need to do is concatenate the files together.